# Developer product successful, even if it should not

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I am making roblox system, where you buy developer products. When you buy it, it sends HTTP request to my server. Then it returns JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Code": 404,
    "Response": "Not Found"
}
```

(it is ok that the code is 404, it should be) Now if the json ["Code"] value is not 200, the function should return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet. I think it does, but even after it roblox says the purchase was successful. But I dont want it. I want it that if the API returns something else than 200, the purchase cant be successful. Here is my code

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local HTTPService = game:GetService("HttpService")

local for1monthid = --productid

MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    local plr = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)
    if not plr then
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end
    if receiptInfo.ProductId == for1monthid then
        local url = "https://api.endpoint.com"
        local data = {
            userid = plr.UserId
        }
        data = HTTPService:JSONEncode(data)
        local response = HTTPService:PostAsync(url, data, Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson, false)
        response = HTTPService:JSONDecode(response)
        if response["Code"] == 200 then
            print(response["Code"])
            return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
        else
            print(response["Code"])
            return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Does `HTTPService:PostAsync` return body of the response?  Or it is just a start of async operation, and you should additionally wait for its complete?

Comment: It returns the json, the request is done @ESkri

Comment: Just to be sure, the prints work. If the response["Code"] is 404, it prints 404 and so on

Comment: Can you print the value of `local response` after `HTTPService:PostAsync`?

Comment: @ESkri it prints the JSON, which is written above. The if statement works, it is being redirected to the else, but the Enum doesn't have any effect looks like

Comment: Which way of `if` it goes?  The correct one?

Comment: It prints 404, as it should (so else)